# Set array element using another array containing path

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
$arr = [
  'foo' => [
    'bar' => [
      1
    ],
    'baz' => [
      1
    ]
  ]
]
```

And another one

```
$path = ['foo', 'bar', 0];
```

I need to modify the value from `$arr` using `$path`. I need the solution to be very simple, I tried something like

```
$arr...$path = 2;
$arr[...$path] = 2;
```

After the modification `$arr` should look like

```
$arr = [
  'foo' => [
    'bar' => [
      2
    ],
    'baz' => [
      1
    ]
  ]
]
```

But I got errors. I don't always know how many levels the array will have.

Comment: its confusing. show the result array you need to recieve from $arr = [
  'foo' => [
    'bar' => [
      1
    ]
  ]
] and $path = ['foo', 'bar'];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path is incorrect -  for `$arr[$path] = 2;` you need

```
$path = ['foo', 'bar', 0];

$p = &$arr;
foreach($path as $step) 
   $p = &$p[$step];
echo $p . "\n";
$p = 2;
print_r($arr);
```

Or with

```
$path = ['foo', 'bar'];

$p = &$arr;
foreach($path as $step) 
   $p = &$p[$step];
echo $p[0] . "\n";
$p[0] = 2;
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$link =& $arr;
foreach ($path AS $p) 
{
    $link =& $link[$p];
}
$link[0]++;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr[$path[0]][$path[1]] ='XXX'
```

Comment: That is not very helpful.